# PL/pgSQL syntax error

Tags: postgresql, syntax, plpgsql

I have a very simple PL/pgSQL script:

```
     declare x varchar(100);
```

When I run it I get a message:

```
    [WARNING  ] declare x varchar(100)
        ERROR:  syntax error at or near "varchar"
        LINE 1: declare x varchar(100)
                          ^
```

I really don't understand what is wrong with this.

Comment: Show the whole create function script

Comment: This is the whole script.

Comment: You must wrap it in a [create function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createfunction.html) command.

Comment: That is **not** a complete (and syntactically correct) PL/pgSQL "script"

Answer (score 26, accepted):

you can use procedural statements **only** inside function body in PostgreSQL.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION foo()
RETURNS int AS 
$$ -- here start procedural part
   DECLARE x int;
   BEGIN
     x := 10;
     RETURN x;
   END;
$$ -- here finish procedural part
LANGUAGE plpgsql; -- language specification
```

or in temporary function (anonymous block)

```
DO $$
DECLARE x int;
BEGIN
  x := 10;
  RAISE NOTICE '>>>%<<<', x;
END;
$$;
```

isn't possible to use procedural statements as SQL statements like T-SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Use exemple

```
DO $$
Declare
  test varchar;
begin
   test := 'teste';
   if (char_length(test) > 0) then
      RAISE NOTICE '>>>%<<<', test;
   end if;
end;
$$;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this by the following piece of code:

```
do $$
declare TypeId int;
declare MasterId int;
begin
   TypeId := null;
   MasterId := null;
end;
$$;
```